# Installing OpenEXR for python causes setuptools to fail with an assertion error

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python

I am trying to install a package that adds OpenEXR bindings to python:
https://github.com/jamesbowman/openexrpython

However, when I run setuptools by executing `pip install .` in the project directory, I get a strange error that seems like the result of an internal typo in python's core packages:

```py
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  running install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  running install_lib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/OpenEXR.cpython-@PYVERNODOTS@m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel                                                                                                                                                      
  copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Imath.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel                                                                                                                                                                                                
  running install_egg_info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  running egg_info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  creating OpenEXR.egg-info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  writing OpenEXR.egg-info/PKG-INFO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  writing dependency_links to OpenEXR.egg-info/dependency_links.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  writing top-level names to OpenEXR.egg-info/top_level.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  writing manifest file 'OpenEXR.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  reading manifest file 'OpenEXR.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  writing manifest file 'OpenEXR.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Copying OpenEXR.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/OpenEXR-1.3.2-py3.7.egg-info                                                                                                                                                                                      
  running install_scripts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    File "/tmp/pip-req-build-rsemsxrd/setup.py", line 25, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      py_modules=['Imath'],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/exrtest/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup                                                                                                                                                                              
      dist.run_commands()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/exrtest/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands                                                                                                                                                                       
      self.run_command(cmd)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/exrtest/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command                                                                                                                                                                        
      cmd_obj.run()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/exrtest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 230, in run                                                                                                                                                               
      impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/exrtest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in get_tag                                                                                                                                                           
      assert tag == supported_tags[0], "%s != %s" % (tag, supported_tags[0])                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  AssertionError: ('cp37', 'cp@pyvernodots@m', 'linux_x86_64') != ('cp37', 'cp@PYVERNODOTS@m', 'linux_x86_64')                                                                                                                                                                 
  ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for OpenEXR
```

As you can see, the cause is an assertion error which is checking that two sets of tags match, which fails because the two strings being compared are `'cp@pyvernodots@m'` and `'cp@PYVERNODOTS@m'`. Clearly the two strings are supposed to be equivalent, but due to a mistake one of them has the wrong capitalization. I don't know enough about the internals of python's package management system to understand where these strings are determined and how I might fix them. The only related resource I could find was this document about compatibility tags, which are evidently the tags causing this malfunction: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/.

My version of python is 3.7.4, installed with anaconda, and this is being done in a fresh environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem installing completely different packages. This seems to be an issue with the python distribution. I had problems with the python 3.7.4 installed by conda. Creating an environment using python 3.7.3 instead fixed my issue. You can do this with:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.7.3`

Edit: As @frmdstryr pointed out in the comments, this is now fixed. Downgrading should now longer be necessary. See the comments for a link to the (now closed) github issue.

Comment: They fixed it now, use `conda update python` to used the latest 3.7.4 build. See https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11195

Comment: @frmdstryr Thanks! Just updated my reply to reflect that.